# Adding images from within the app based on json response from url in a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, imageview, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionViewCell` that has a label and an `imageView`. I'm dynamically populating the `label` by storing the `json` response in an `array`.

Based on the response that i receive from the url I want to append an `image` to it.

For example if my label is populated with "Fridge". I want to display an `image` of fridge in my `imageView`. The images are stored in `Assets.xcassets` folder.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Get an idea from https://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/ . Same thing is implemented as you are looking. Once you understand the basics, try to check swift tableview examples and convert your code for swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store all the images in your `Assets.xcassets`, when you declare the cell (`cellForItemAtIndexPath`) and assign the data to it, you can just do something like:

```
cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: YOUR_LABEL_VALUE)
```

If you store the images in .png format, with the same name of the labels you are gonna use, that can work.

For examples your labels are:

- Fridge
- Microwave
- Sink

So your images in your Assets.xcassets:

- Fridge.png
- Microwave.png
- Sink.png